# Easy way for no-content without controller

Tags: spring, spring-security

I am using Spring Security with Spring Controllers. There are some weird requests caused by some third party browser extension ending such as `undefined` or weird hexadecimal numbers. I would like to configure my application to block these requests but I could not find an easy way.

I do not want to declare a empty controller for this purpose. What is the correct way to return `no-content` for these requests?

Edit:

Some sample requets:

```
/activity/favorites/undefined
/activity/favorites/my/undefined
/help/undefined
```

Comment: Can you provide an example HTTP request in your question?

Comment: @nobeh added some samples.

Answer (score 1):

Create some servlet filter that is invoked for every request (*). That filter has to check the request URL, and if it is on of the "strangers" that return what you want, but prevent the request from being future processed.